# Zonal Statistics - the algorithm computes the average statistics for all the polygons of the layer vector

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

Using QGIS, I want to compute the average elevation per 1890 US counties. I have a shapefile with the 1890 counties boundaries with fixed geometry, and STRM elevation data, saved as a GeoTIFF file. Once I have imported the vector and raster layers, I use the Zonal Statistics plug-in to obtain my statistic per county. However, the algorithm computes only one average for the whole area covered by the polygons (counties), and returns it for the first observation of my vector layer. All the other observations have missing values.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with some of my own data. I get a similar output if the layers do not have the same coordinate reference system. Could this be the case in your project?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My issue also stemmed from differential coordinate reference systems, where one of my vector layers was entirely included in one polygon of the other. It explains why it computed the global average for one observation only. But thanks for your help.